# Question about $\gamma^{0}$ matrix

Tags: conventions, notation, dirac-matrices

I see different definitions in different places so here is my question.

why is $\gamma^{0}$ sometimes defined as a 2 by 2 matrix and sometimes as a 4 by 4 matrix? shouldn't a definition be something that does not change?

Comment: Do you mean perhaps a $2\times 2$ matrix of a $2 \times 2$ matrix (making it actually $4\times 4$)? Sometimes that's the way it is displayed in textbooks.

Comment: I have 1 in the first element of the first row and -1 on the last element of the last row. It dosen't say that it is something different than 1. however, do you mean it is definitely always as a 4 by 4 matrix?

Comment: It is as I suspected, here 1 means the 2 by 2 identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the very common block matrix notation. When you see

$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

you should interpret this as

$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} I_{2\times 2} & 0_{2\times 2} \\ 0_{2\times 2} & -I_{2\times 2} \end{pmatrix}, $$

where $I_{2\times 2}$ and $0_{2\times 2}$ are the $2\times 2$ identity and zero matrices. Written out in full the matrix would be

$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

There are two things going on here, really. One is that physicists like to write the identity matrix as $1$ instead of $I$, and the other is the block matrix notation, where it is assumed that you know from context that  $\gamma^0$ should be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Many times we don't even write the zero matrices, so that you could even see

$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \\ & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

being used! You just have to know from context that this is supposed to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix, and the $1$'s are $2 \times 2$ identities.

Comment: Great answer Javier- thanks! Well explained. This should clear up any confusion surrounding the use of 1 vs . Just to clarify for any other readers, the "implied" matrix (read across rows) ^0=(_2×2, 0_2×2, 0_2×2, _2×2) should in fact be ^0=(_2×2, 0_2×2, 0_2×2, -_2×2); the - is what contributes to the two -1s that you see at ^0_3,3 and ^0_4,4. hope this helps!

Comment: @FrederikPusch edited, thanks for the correction.